# Can I change the disk size and RAM size of a VM via GUI in KVM (virt-manager)?

Tags: virt-manager

I want to change the disk size and RAM size of a KVM virtual machine. In the `virt-manager`, I cannot find any Settings menue to achieve this. Is it possible via GUI?